# Does `Code Navigation` in Visual Studio Code support Multi-root Workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working with multiple projects in Visual Studio Code (a "multi-root workspace") I would like Code Navigation to search all the projects.

For example having `projectA` and `projectB` in a multi-root workspace.

`projectA` defines a class `Car` and `projectB` defines a class `Driver`. Driver holds an instance of Car.

Now, using "find all references" of `Car` I would like to see `Driver` in the search results. But in my setup only references from the containing root (`projectA`) are found.

Is there a way to achieve this? How do I configure a multi-root workspace to have Code Navigation search in all projects of the workspace?